# Can't access Main class variables

Tags: c#, .net, program-entry-point, class-variables

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SomeColors
{
    class Program
    {
        private static int currentCursorX = Console.CursorLeft;
        private static int currentCursorY = Console.CursorTop;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
   }
}
```

So I can't access my `Program` class variables `currentCursorX` and `currentCursorY`.
Why is that?

Comment: What do you mean you can't access? Do you get an error?

Comment: You try to access it from _where_?

Comment: Those are static fields, not "global variables". C# is an object-based language, not a procedural one. It might be worth it to read a bit about the differences between the two - you should understand your error quite early on.

Comment: @Luaan So if I will make them non static I could access them as class variables from Main?

Comment: No, because `Main` is also `static`. You should really read up at least on the basics - what a class is, what fields are, what's the difference between instance members and static members and what's the deal with access modifiers.

Comment: @Luaan Ok Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access `private` variables just inside the class they have defined (`Program` in your case)!

Make them `public` so you can access them from other classes.

```
public static int currentCursorX = Console.CursorLeft;
public static int currentCursorY = Console.CursorTop;
```

You should read more about [Access Modifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx). Although keep in mind that having public fields in your classes is not a good approach.

Comment: Oh, the `public` modifier did the job. Thanks a lot man. But they are class variables no? like when you start a new class you define them `private` , why here it not works?

Comment: Make them "pubic" so you can access them from other classes.

Comment: @InHere from where are you trying to access them? you have them defined as static so you should be able to access them from anywhere through the scope operator once they're public

Comment: Im trying to access them from Main method.

Comment: @InHere Hmm, no. You must be missing some critical piece of code. A `private static` field would be available in a static method defined in the same class (i.e. `Main` will see static private fields in `Program`). You're skipping something.

Answer (score 0):

use below code if you are accessing it from outside the assembly:

```
public class Program
    {
        public static int currentCursorX = Console.CursorLeft;
        public static int currentCursorY = Console.CursorTop;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }
   }
```

**in your class**

```
using SomeColors;

class Class1
{
    int i= Program.currentCursorX;
}
```